# Android trying to override style changes it completely

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I have this in my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/AppSpinnerStyle</item>
    <!-- snip -->
</style>

<style name="AppSpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <!-- My custom changes to go here -->
</style>
```

Overriding android:spinnerStyle like this changes the appearance of the spinners completely. Even without applying any of my own custom changes.

I can only imagine that by inheriting android:Widget.Spinner I am getting some sort of default styling instead of the theme styling.

How do I inherit the style from the theme?

**EDIT**

I guess what I really need to know is, how can I tell what android:spinnerStyle was referencing before I changed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inheriting from android:Widget.Spinner which is not AppCompat widget, so it won't have the look that should have the spinner from the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

I didn't try them myself but, try using these:

```
Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar
Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar
```

If you are using rev 22 of AppCompat v7 then you can try also:

```
Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined
```

Comment: OK all 3 of those look "correct" (they all look identical to me - at least against a black background anyway). Where do you find these "items" (what are they called?). It seems I'm forever trawling google to find out what's going on with my styling. Somehow I feel, the answers are probably there in this vast program called Android Studio but I'm really struggling to know where to look. I'm updating the question too.

Comment: press Ctrl + Click of the mouse on the item, and you will be able to see its code. See the differences and adapt to your app.

Comment: for looking into the spinner the DarkActionBar theme is using, maybe you see a reference to it in the code

Comment: OK Ctrl-click is "Go to declaration" which is useful to know. Or ctrl-B if you prefer the keyboard. I hadn't considered that the "Go to" context menu would work for XML as well as Java